# Handling different json inputs in Lambda python

Tags: python, json, aws-lambda

Need a recommendation on how to handle this. I have a python lambda function that accepts in json. There could be 10 different types of payload.

For example:

```
{
  "animalType": "dog",
  "name": "josie",
  ...
}
```

another app can send in:

```
{
  "animalType": "cheeta",
  "name": "cheetos",
  ...
}
```

another app can send in:

```
{
  "furniture": "chair",
  "storeName": "Freedom furniture",
  ...
}
```

I want to apply different logic based on the payload that is sent in.

Do you think it's wise to:

```
if "animalType" in json.dumps(event):

    ...do something

elseif "furniture" in json.dumps(event):

    ...do something

else

    ...do something
```

any thoughts? the ...do something area could be pretty long and I want to consider these separate modules, so should I call another function?

Answer (score 1):

````
'''
{
  "animalType": "dog",
  "name": "josie",
  ...
}
'''

'''
{
  "animalType": "cheeta",
  "name": "cheetos",
  ...
}
'''

'''
{
  "furniture": "chair",
  "storeName": "Freedom furniture",
  ...
}
'''

You can also do like this one:-
```
#for animalType do this
def animalType():
    pass
#for furniture do this
def furniture():
    pass


caller={"animalType":animalType(),
        "furniture":furniture()}

'''
if you are using >=python3.6 version  , for key ordering
if order of inserting these keys (animalType,furniture) in dict is
  always same then you can use index to access the value as below
if you are getting your animalType on 0th index 
'''
key=list(events.keys())[0]
caller[key]



```
````

Comment: Thank you for your response. If the def is fairly long, and I want to keep it in a separate module, how would I do that?

Comment: ok im guessing my answer is not good enough for you? ill delete it lol

Comment: @JimmyChen
You can do that also.
Just make the module in one file .
and import functions in another file.
And make a dict in that value as imported function.
Like-
file1.py
   ```def f1():
        pass
   def f2():
      pass```
file2.py
 ```import file1.* 
     caller={"f1":f1(),"f2":f2()}
```

Comment: @BlackFox no no... actually, I haven't digested it yet... Please post again. I really appreciate it... Still trying to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

so just store the output in a data struct. Core Dev solution here:

```
# using a data structure: Array (in python a list)
data_list =[]

# you will need to learn to use the requests lib
import requests

data = requests.post(
            url="https://endpoint/api1/").json()

''' 
   print() is a basic way to test data 
   to see if returns what is expected or not
'''
# print(data) 

'''
   Looping through iterative data structures is a key skill 
   and will be used a lot in all levels of python programing
'''

for d in data:
    data_list.append(d)
```

Now that you have the data in a data_list you can loop through it and use constants to get back the logic you need:

```
for data in data_list:
    ''' 
        An algorithm is a list of steps, 
        and conditional statements help control 
        the flow of data through each step. 
        A if statement is a basic example to control 
        the logic of your algorithm
    '''

    if data['animalType'] == "foo":
           ...do something
    if data['animalType'] == "bar":
           ...do something
```

you can repeat this logic as needed. One of the most powerful ways to get started with data structure, design algorithms and OOP.

I say OOP as this logic can be optimized by not just adding functions to deal with new dynamic use case and future requirements, but the above logic can also be refactored to use classes using OOP concepts.

you will evolve as you learn and explore:

```
1. Procedural programing ( logic like presented in this example)
2. Functional Programing ( adding functions to deal with dynamic inputs and outputs)
3. OOP ( adding classes to create a reusable Dynamic systems for your programs requirements) 
4. Data structures and design algorithms (the proving ground to get a job as a pro developer)
```

happy coding:)